# Use MSAL to retrieve authorization token on Mono for MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use the MSAL library in order to retrieve an Azure AD B2C authentication token from a desktop .net app on MacOS to call a secured API. This is working perfectly fine when building against `dotnetcore`:

```
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithB2CAuthority(AuthoritySignUpSignIn)
                .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUrl)
                .Build();

IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync(PolicySignUpSignIn);

AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(ApiScopes)
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
                .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();
```

However, since this application will run as an embedded plugin I need to build against a .net framework target. Running the same code built against `net48` target and executed on Mono for Mac some exceptions occur (see below).

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PlatformsCommon.Shared.DesktopOsHelper.GetWindowsVersionStringInternal () [0x0000f] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PlatformsCommon.Shared.DesktopOsHelper+<>c.<.cctor>b__18_2 () [0x00000] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x00043] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [0x00022] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x0000a] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PlatformsCommon.Shared.DesktopOsHelper.GetWindowsVersionString () [0x00000] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.net45.NetDesktopPlatformProxy.InternalGetOperatingSystem () [0x00000] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x00043] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [0x00022] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x0000a] in <3a5ca7554402454690eb498ecf91eca6>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PlatformsCommon.Shared.AbstractPlatformProxy.GetOperatingSystem () [0x00000] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.MsalIdHelper.GetMsalIdParameters (Microsoft.Identity.Client.Core.ICoreLogger logger) [0x00057] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.CreateAuthorizationRequestParameters (System.Uri redirectUriOverride) [0x00223] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.CreateAuthorizationUri (System.Boolean addPkceAndState) [0x00000] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync (Microsoft.Identity.Client.UI.IWebUI webUi, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00046] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0007d] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.GetTokenResponseAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00182] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.ExecuteAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fa] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001e2] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Parameters.AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Parameters.AcquireTokenInteractiveParameters interactiveParameters, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00142] in <b9a99487e27c4dd08624b5deef1ad993>:0 
  at up_console.Program.RunAsync () [0x00142] in <e5a2c54d28494d56b9935be85f2b417a>:0 
  at up_console.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000d] in <e5a2c54d28494d56b9935be85f2b417a>:0
```

I did also try using a [CustomWebUi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.extensibility.icustomwebui?view=azure-dotnet), but this doesn't change anything.

Reading the [official MSAL.net requirements](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet#requirements) I understand that Mono on MacOS doesn't seem to be supported, however in some [older release notes](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-2.6.0-released#msalnet-260-brings-a-more-rational-net-standard-public-api-with-a-few-actionable-platformnotsupportedexception) Mono is mentioned:

> In some cases, the .NET standard 1.3 assembly can also be used at runtime. That is, for instance, the case if the application you are building is for a platform that MSAL.NET does not support explicitly. Examples of such platforms are Xamarin.Mac, Unity, **Mono**, or old frameworks such as Windows Phone, Windows Phone Silverlight.

Any ideas on how to get MSAL.net running on Mono for Mac?

Comment: net452 dates back a long way, and netstandard1.3 was a very early attempt at cross platform standardisation, so I would not be optimistic. Is there a reason you can't target net48?

Comment: @ste-fu good point, using `net48` is producing the same error. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Looking in a little more detail, the exception says `GetWindowsVersionStringInternal` which does not sound hopeful

Comment: Due to .NET 5/6, most libraries are no longer compatible with Mono. You just hit one of the typical cases. Don't let old release notes bother you. They were written a long while ago when things were different.